# C/C++ мультиплатформенное получение peer IP

Tags: c++, linux, windows, .net, сеть

Я читал что можно получить ip при server accept, но мне нужно получать его в любое время, используя winsock2 для windows и arpa/inet для linux. Есть ли сайт где расписаны все мультиплатформенные запросы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html для посиксов.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getpeername для виндовс.

Функция совместима, ничего дополнитель кроссплатформить не нужно.